# how to use automator to send new tweet?

Tags: macos, twitter, applescript, automator

relating to this post, https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/70585/applescript-opens-new-window-for-everything-when-run.

I wonder if i can highlight the selected text and run this service, can i have the selected text in the new tweet textbox?

Here's the current codes:

```
    activate application "Tweetbot"
tell application "System Events"
  tell process "Tweetbot"
      repeat until exists
          delay 0.4
      end repeat
      set frontmost to true
      delay 0.2
      keystroke "n" using command down
  end tell
end tell
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/aahdK.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/pHtkX.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the selected text as a variable in Automator and use UI scripting to set the contents of the text field.

```
on run {input, parameters}
    activate application "Tweetbot"
    tell application "System Events" to tell process "Tweetbot"
        keystroke "n" using command down
        set value of text area 1 of scroll area 1 of window 1 to (input as text)
    end tell
end run
```

If you run the script with a shortcut that has other modifier keys than command, try replacing `keystroke "n" using command down` with `click menu item "New Tweet" of menu 1 of menu bar item "Tweet" of menu bar 1`.